# Search IList of KeyValuePairs for two keys

Tags: linq, list, keyvaluepair

I am putting in a temporary fix to code in which we want to validate attributes on an item. These are "swatchImageUrl" and "swatchVariantAttribute". If either one of these is provided, the other *must* be provided. Where I will check this is on a dictionary of the values. So what I have in place is the following:

```
if((transformedValues.Any(t => t.Key.Equals("swatchImageUrl")) &&
   !transformedValues.Any(t => t.Key.Equals("swatchVariantAttribute"))) ||
   (transformedValues.Any(t => t.Key.Equals("swatchVariantAttribute")) &&
   !transformedValues.Any(t => t.Key.Equals("swatchImageUrl"))))
   {
       // throw an error here
   }
```

This feels clunky and possibly inefficient (transformedValues will possibly be a very large list and my understanding is .Any() will end up enumerating the whole list if there are none) but I cannot think of a nicer way of doing this. 'transformedItems' is an IList of string key value pairs (so I can't use .ContainsKey etc.)

Is there some nice neater way of doing this that I am missing? Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: `if (transformedValues.Any(t => t.Key.Equals("swatchImageUrl")) != transformedValues.Any(t => t.Key.Equals("swatchVariantAttribute"))) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: A classical example when people make Boolean expressions more difficult than needed. Your statements seem like: If A is true and B is false or if A is false or B is true, while in fact you mean: if A and B are not both true or not both false, or simply if A != B

Comment: THANK you both! I knew I was over thinking this. @HaraldDutch, yep a classic example of making it more difficult than necessary. Sometimes you need to step away before coming back and realising how simple things really are.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is having similar brainfreeze. The obvious way to do this in a better way is as ASh pointed out;

```
if(transformedValues.Any(t => t.Key.Equals("swatchImageUrl")) != transformedValues.Any(t => t.Key.Equals("swatchVariantAttribute"))) 
{ /*...*/ }
```